Leer respuesta XML de SOAP con PHP
Estoy realizando una petición con SOAP y obtengo la siguiente respuesta en XML.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ns1:obtenerDatosInfraResp soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://ep.ws.transito.solvencia.sat.gob.gt">
                <obtenerDatosInfranRet soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[][1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                    <obtenerDatosInfranRet soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                        <obtenerDatosInfranRet xsi:type="soapenc:string">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
    &lt;MSGINFRA&gt;
      &lt;MSGRESP&gt;
        &lt;CODIGO&gt;2&lt;/CODIGO&gt;
        &lt;DESCRI&gt;&lt;![CDATA[PARAMETROS REQUERIDOS]]&gt;&lt;/DESCRI&gt;
      &lt;/MSGRESP&gt;
    &lt;/MSGINFRA&gt;
    
    </obtenerDatosInfranRet>
                    </obtenerDatosInfranRet>
                </obtenerDatosInfranRet>
            </ns1:obtenerDatosInfraResp>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>

Lo que quiero obtener es la información de la etiqueta CODIGO
&lt;CODIGO&gt;2&lt;/CODIGO&gt;

He intentado realizar lo siguiente con PHP, apoyándome de respuestas de problemas similares.
$library = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

$ns = $library->getDocNamespaces();

$ext1 = $library->children($ns['soapenv']);
$ext2 = $ext1->Body;
var_dump($ext2);

Honestamente no tengo muchos conocimientos en el manejo de XML, por lo que agradezco la ayuda u orientación que puedan proporcionar.

Ya que estas trabajando SimpleXMLElement, podés aprovechar y utilizar el método xpath()

El método xpath busca el nodo SimpleXML para los hijos que cumplan la path XPath.
Retorna un array de objetos SimpleXMLElement o false en caso de error.

Solución:

Cargamos el XML y obtenemos el documento.
En el documento buscamos el elemento //obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn/obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn/obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn.
De dicho elemento obtenemos su contenido, que es un XML.
Cargamos este nuevo XML y obtenemos un nuevo documento.
En el documento buscamos el elemento //COD
De dicho elemento obtenemos su contenido.

Ejemplo:
<?php
$result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:obtenerDatosInfraccionResponse soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://ep.ws.transito.solvencia.sat.gob.gt\">
            <obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn soapenc:arrayType=\"soapenc:string[][1]\" xsi:type=\"soapenc:Array\" xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">
                <obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn soapenc:arrayType=\"soapenc:string[1]\" xsi:type=\"soapenc:Array\">
                    <obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn xsi:type=\"soapenc:string\">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;RESMSGRESETINFRA&gt;
  &lt;MSGRESP&gt;
    &lt;COD&gt;2&lt;/COD&gt;
    &lt;DESC&gt;&lt;![CDATA[NO SE RECIBIERON TODOS LOS PARAMETROS REQUERIDOS]]&gt;&lt;/DESC&gt;
  &lt;/MSGRESP&gt;
&lt;/RESMSGRESETINFRA&gt;

</obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn>
                </obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn>
            </obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn>
        </ns1:obtenerDatosInfraccionResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

// Cargamos el XML
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
// Accedemos al XML dentro del elemento
$xml = $doc->xpath("//obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn/obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn/obtenerDatosInfraccionReturn")[0]->__toString();
// Cargamos el XML
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
// Buscamos el código
$code = $doc->xpath("//COD")[0]->__toString();
//
echo $code;
// Output: 2

Demo

Agradezco mucho la ayuda @Marcos, efectivamente es la solución que buscaba, tuve que solucionar algunos problemas con mi código pero funciono, esto me viene perfecto para adquirir más conocimientos. GRACIAS.
